# How to access ejabberd server's web admin interface?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am new to the xmpp server and still learning. I have chosen ejabberd server for my chat application. I have started the server but can't able to access the web admin interface. [as you can see the ejabberd@localhost is already running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBWJF.png). [configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7sDY.png)

I started the server and it was supposed to show web admin interface but unfortunately it is not showing. I don't know what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With that configuration, the webadmin page is in
http://localhost:5280/admin/

When the browser asks login credentials, provide the JID of some account in ejabberd with admin rights (it may be vinayak@localhost or something like that) and its password.

This means that you should have already registered an account in ejabberd, and grant it admin rights in ejabberd.yml configuration file, see https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/installation/#administration-account